# R hash or unique id of variable

Tags: r, hash, memory-address, internals, objectid

Is there an alternative to inspect function to retrieve address or hash of a variable in R that would be compatible with MIT licence?

Today I use:

```
id = function(x) {
  txt <- capture.output(.Internal(inspect(x, 1)))[[1]]
  return(regmatches(txt,regexpr("@[^ ]+",txt)))
}
```

to get address of any variable (either environment or vector) that identifies its uniquely.

I would like to post my library to CRAN and unfortunately my solution is not recommended way. Running CHECK:

> checking R code for possible problems ... WARNING
>
> Found a .Internal call in the following function:
>
> ‘id’
>
> with calls to .Internal functions
>
> ‘inspect’

Comment: `pryr::inspect(mtcars)$address`

Comment: pryr as I see is GPL-2 so I couldn't use it my library that is MIT

Comment: @hrbrmstr is `pryr::address(mtcars)` the same and better?

Comment: @MarekJagielski How do you define "unique"? `y=1;x=y;address(x)==address(y)` returns `TRUE`.

Comment: @Spacedman I went with the one that produced the same value the OP had. OP: apologies abt the MIT thing, but calling the same low-level R stuff `pryr` uses [here](https://github.com/hadley/pryr/blob/master/src/inspect.cpp) will give you the functionality you need w/o the CRAN warning and keeping it MIT. You could also explain to the CRAN mods what you're doing and why. They are great chaps and may allow your original code depending on the use-case.

Comment: @Spacedman about unique: My usecase is that I have e.g. list of R6 classes or other list and also I have maps like map <- new.env(hash=TRUE) where I keep related variables to elements of initial list. Then I can access to related things by: related_element <- map[[id(element)]].

Comment: @hrbrmstr: please post that as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I used a low level C implementation:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>

SEXP id(SEXP x)
{
    char buffer[32];
    snprintf(buffer, 32, "%p", (void *)x);
    return(ScalarString(mkChar(buffer)));
}
```